# Drupal Migrate Questions

Tags: 7, migrations

I am migrating from a table in the database into a Drupal content type.
I have a field that is using a taxonomy reference that has a hierarchy.
The problem i am facing is when the taxonomy is in this format.

Phone->Mobile->Samsung
Tablet->Samsung.

I have the terms hierarchy saved with a comma separator.
Used explode to split and choose only last term and his parent.
The question is how i pick the parent name for that taxonomy term tried the following code since it's the only one i can find regarding this but i doesn't work.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('parent_name', 'category_parent')
  ->arguments(array('source_type' => 'field_product_category'));
```

Also i wan to create a different class that imports the terms with they're parents prior to the other migration, what is my best option to create a hierarchy like this

Top Term->Child1->Subchild1->Subsubchild1

Creating a structure like this : Term->Child is easy the problem is when i have multiple levels.